# R ggplot geom_point color gradient based on variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot London postcodes with ggplot, and I would like the value of colour of each point to vary based on a 3rd variable. The code I have for the initial plot is:

```
gg <- ggplot() + geom_point(data=joined_data, aes(x=V3, y=V4), color = '#800080', size=0.2, alpha=0.5)
print(gg)
```

this is all set to a single colour though, how can I set the colour value to vary based on the 3rd variable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Is the 3rd variable continuous?

Comment: yes, ranges from 0 to 10,000,000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming V5 is your 3rd variable (It must be a column in joined_data.

```
ggplot(joined_data, aes(x = V3, y = V4, color = V5)) + geom_point()
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set the `colour` aesthetic first, then use a continuous color scale to choose the gradient of colors.

I have used the built-in data set `iris`, transformed.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df1, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, colour = clr)) +
  geom_point(size = 1, alpha=0.5) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "#800080", high = "#FF00FF")
```

[image]

**Data.**

The `ave` instruction creates a color column `clr`, depending on the maxima of `Sepal.Length` by `Species`.

```
df1 <- iris
df1$clr <- ave(df1$Sepal.Length, df1$Species, FUN = function(x){
  runif(length(x), 0, max(x))
})
```